# Why do I hear my own echo (feedback) in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am hearing myself when I talk in Teams. When I uncheck 'Listen to this device' I can't hear myself at all when I do the echo service test during playback. The Microphone setting in the Levels tab is set to 0. Supposedly this is so I don't get any echo.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please explain more what happens when 'Listen to this device' is unchecked.

Comment: @harrymc More what? If I can't hear what I said during the test call, people won't hear me during a real meeting.

Comment: Do you mean that this disables your microphone?

Comment: I just did a test now to see if the mic input meter registers anything if the checkbox is unchecked. It did and the playback worked. Weird. This seems to be sporadic. I have to do a mic test before every meeting. Once the test fails, I have to check/uncheck the box. close the sound appley, test again, disable/enable the mic, restart Teams and so on until it works. It's time consuming and random.